# Unable to test setter/getter method inside of LWC using jest testing framework

Tags: testing, jestjs, getter-setter, lwc

I am trying to test LWC components.js using jest. There is a setter method(Step) inside of the LWC components js file, but I am unable to test the setter method. I tried the solution using mock that the jest provided for the setter method.

[image]

Another approach that I tried for testing getter using  jest.spyOn(ClassName, MethodName, MethodType).mockReturnValue(0);

[image]

Any alternative approach of jest testing for the setter method..?

Comment: Don't add screenshot image for your code.Please edit your question with minimal reproducing code.

Comment: Thanks, @slideshowp2. I remove two to three screenshots. I hope, this screenshot will help me.

Comment: Hi, this is the issue that I am facing while testing the LWC using Jest for a long time, so anybody knows let me know here ASAP.

Comment: Its years later but was there a solution for this?